# Which one is correct in the context:"have" Or "has"

Tags: grammar

> 1) Our team of nationally recognized trainers has earned multiple titles….

In the first version *team* is the object making *has* correct.

Or

> 2) Our team of nationally recognized trainers have earned multiple titles….

In the second version *trainers* is the object making *have* correct.

Comment: Probably in this case, you want to emphasize the _team_ aspect, so you would want to use the singular, pinning the credit squarely on the Team.

Comment: *Team* can be plural: [*The team are meeting infrequently and have no team area.*](http://books.google.com/books?id=LCsFMKrclp8C&pg=PA129&dq=%22team+are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=U7KBUdvGIZLOyAG464DwDA&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCw)

Comment: Who earned the titles? Was it the trainers individually, or was it the team as a whole?

Comment: The 2nd version is ambiguous, it should like: `Our team of nationally recognized trainers who have earned multiple titles...` . If we think for 1st version in this manner, it becomes: `Our team of nationally recognized trainers which has earned multiple titles...` makes it more readable, I think.